# Postgres: pull two non-overlapping sets of data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to pull 30K rows at random from our data store to create one data set, then 30K more rows for a second data set that doesn't overlap any ids with the first.

My idea for how to make it would would be to somehow reference the id columns pulled in the first subquery when drawing a second subquery, then return their union:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id_col, A, B, C, 'group1' as label
    FROM my_db
    LIMIT 30000
) as t1
UNION ALL
(

        SELECT id_col, A, B, C, 'group2' as label
        FROM my_db
        WHERE id_col NOT IN t1.id_col
        LIMIT 30000

) as t2
```

But this does not work as I get "syntax error at or near t1" .

Updated: add label to column to show how a union would have created a tall format for the two groups.

Comment: If you need two data sets, why not insert them in to two temp tables? Why are you trying to union them? That just creates a Single data set...

Comment: Place the first query in the WITH section of a [common table expression.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

Comment: @MatBailie I have never used temp tables so maybe that is what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As klin pointed out in the comments, you would need to use a Common Table Expression (CTE) in order to achieve your desired result:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT id_col, A, B, C, 'group1' AS label
    FROM my_db
    LIMIT 30000
), t2 AS (
    SELECT id_col, A, B, C, 'group2' AS label
    FROM my_db
    WHERE id_col NOT IN (SELECT id_col FROM t1)
    LIMIT 30000
)

SELECT id_col, A, B, C, label
FROM t1
UNION
SELECT id_col, A, B, C, label
FROM t2
```

You also would not need to do a UNION ALL, a UNION should suffice.

Comment: Despite there being no duplicates, due to literal and selection criteria, UNION will likely perform a sort in order to eliminate duplicates.  UNION ALL does not perform sort to remove duplicates so it would seem a better option.